# how to get image file, using Scrapy

Tags: python, image, scrapy, web-crawler

I just started to use Scrapy and I'm trying to crawl image file. Here is my code.

items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class TutorialItem(Item):
    image_urls = Field(
    images = Field()
    pass
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGE_STORE = '/Users/rnd/Desktop/Scrapy-0.16.5/tutorial/images'
```

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class TutorialPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    return item

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
    yield Request(image_url)
```

tutorial_spider.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class TutorialSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "tutorial"
allowed_domains = ["roxie.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.roxie.com/events/details.cfm?eventid=581D228B%2DB338%2DF449%2DBD69027D7D878A7F"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = TutorialItem()
    link = hxs.select('//div[@id="eventdescription"]//img/@src').extract()
    item['image_urls'] = ["http://www.roxie.com" + link]
    return item
```

printed log - command >> scrapy crawl tutorial -o roxie.json -t json

```
2013-06-19 17:29:06-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: tutorial)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted/web/microdom.py:181: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
assert (oldChild.parentNode is self,
2013-06-19 17:29:06-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-06-19 17:29:06-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-06-19 17:29:06-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
 pkg_resources.run_script('Scrapy==0.16.5', 'scrapy')
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script

 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1207, in run_script
 # we assume here that our metadata may be nested inside a "basket"
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
execute()
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 131, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 76, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/command.py", line 33, in crawler
self._crawler.configure()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 41, in configure
self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 63, in __init__
self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in __init__
self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/middleware.py", line 29, in from_settings
mwcls = load_object(clspath)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.6.egg/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 39, in load_object
raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': No module named PIL
```

It looks like need for PIL, so I installed.

```
PIL 1.1.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pilconvert.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pildriver.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilfile.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilfont.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilprint.py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
Processing dependencies for pil
Finished processing dependencies for pil
```

However, it doesn't work. Could you let me know what I missed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are still getting `No module named PIL` or what kind of error?

Comment: Are you able to import PIL via the Python interpreter?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, I still have same error.

Comment: @Talvalin I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Could you let me know how to import PIL?

Comment: Try `import PIL` in the python interpreter - any errors?

Comment: Assuming Python has been installed correctly, type 'python' at the command prompt and then type 'import pil' - do any errors occur?

Comment: Oh I just saw you guys' comments. I tried, it says 'ImportError: No module named pil'

Comment: Guys, is there any error in code? :(

Comment: Try browsing to the /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages directory, typing 'ln -s PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg PIL' to create a symlink and then try the import command again (with 'pil' in capitals). If that works, then try running your spider code again.

Comment: @Talvalin Thanks! There is no error message on screen, the image wasn't stored. I think it is because of pipeline, so I have browsed up and tried some different ways, but still doesn't work. :( What do you think about this?

Comment: Does the import from the Python interpreter now work?

Comment: Yes. so now it seems working well, but as I commented, the image wasn't stored.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I got the same problem when I started to crawl pics from some sites. I worked in CentOs6.5 ,python2.7.6. I solved it as this below:

yum install easy_install

easy_install pip

Then login as root and use command: pip install image. And everything just worked.

If you worked in Ubuntu , I think the trick just is: sudo apt-get install easy_install and the next will be same I think.

I hope it will be some helpful .